# +1234567 ends up being 1234567... where is the plus?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Well through jquery i am doing an ajax request to send through a cell number in the format of +1234567 but if i access it on the other end using `$_POST['cell'];` the plus is gone, where could it be?

Comment: You need to post snippets of JS and PHP.

Comment: It's not gone, it's replaced by a space which is what `+` means in an URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on how you are performing the query.

If you do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.php',
    data: 'cell=+1234567'
});
```

You will loose the `+` because it because it has to be URL encoded (`+` means space in the URL). I would recommend you this which will take care of encoding:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.php',
    data: { cell: '+12345' }
});
```